# Blank Column value in Microsoft Query Results in Excel 2016

Tags: sql-server

I am able to successfully view the records in SQL Server Management Studio but when I import the data in EXCEL using Microsoft Query it shows all the records as empty with the same query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING(FTR.[OVERRIDE], 1, 30) AS over_ride 
FROM 
    [mydb].[dbo].[FTR] FTR 
WHERE
    FTR.AUTH_DATE BETWEEN '2020-01-02' AND '2020-01-10' 
    AND FTR.[OVERRIDE] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Then I would suggest the queries are not the same, or the connection settings are. Perhaps you are using English US for one connection, and English for the other, meaning that the dates would be interpreted as 01 Feburary 2020 and 10 Janurary 2020 (which would never return results) and 02 January 2020 and 10 January 2020. If you use an unambigous format for your dates (`yyyyMMdd`) dose it work as you expect on both?

Comment: I am getting 55 records both in SQL and Excel other fields are appearing but not this field in Excel Query.